# How far should a TEC1-12706 peltier module be away from the heat source to prevent damage when using it to generate thermoelectricity?

Tags: peltier

I am working on my science fair project and only have 5 peliter modules. In order to build my project I need to know how far it must be to keep from being damaged because I can not replace these once I have begun.

Comment: how far away from what?

Comment: far enough away to keep its temperature within data sheet specifications.

Comment: @Trevor   From the heat source/candle I will be using, I don't want to burn the thing out on my first run as I will be needing it for multiple trials

Comment: Underspecified. You need to not exceed rated temperature. If you wait to ask how to achieve that with your setup you need to describe the setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you add a piece of aluminum block around 3-4 mm thick with good quality thermal paste and then bring it close to the candle at a distance and at the same time measure the temperature of the aluminum block. Make sure you stay below the limit around 55-65C since 75C is max temp. Because too much heat you will melt the solder connections inside and ruin it. Good luck!